# Django failed to build wheel for python-ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap

I'm new to **Python Django**, I have integrated my Django application on *Windows 7* machine. When I tried to integrate LDAP by using `pip install django-auth-ldap` but unfortunately I got an error

```
    Failed building wheel for python-ldap
    Running setup.py clean for python-ldap
    Failed to build python-ldap
    django-python3-ldap 0.11.1 has requirement pyasn1==0.3.2, but you'll have pyasn1 0.4.4 which is incompatible.
```

Please help me to escape me from this issue, bcz I have been struck here for a couple of days

Answer (score 1):

I think this message is pretty clear:

> django-python3-ldap 0.11.1 has requirement pyasn1==0.3.2, but you'll have pyasn1 0.4.4 which is incompatible.

When using *django-python3-ldap* you have to explicitly use version 0.3.2 of module *pyasn1*. But something else already installed a newer version of *pyasn1* to you build environment.

So you have to specify version pinning information in [install_requires or requirements files](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/).

Answer (score -1):

Try Updating pip using

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Hi @Ethan Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (18.0)

Comment: This is what I got error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\
VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'